# Following a book "Programming Phoenix >= 1.4", got stuck at "Testing Logged-Out Users"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following a book "Programming Phoenix >= 1.4", got stuck at "Testing Logged-Out Users" (Integration Tests, page 161). Test fail.

video_controller_test.exs

```
    defmodule RumblWeb.VideoControllerTest do
    use RumblWeb.ConnCase, async: true
  
    test "requires user authentication on all actions", %{conn: conn} do
      Enum.each([
        get(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :new)),
        get(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :index)),
        get(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :show, "123")),
        get(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :edit, "123")),
        put(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :update, "123", %{})),
        post(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :create, %{})),
        delete(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :delete, "123")),
      ], fn conn ->
        assert html_response(conn, 302)
        assert conn.halted
      end)
    end
  end
```

mix test test/rumbl_web

```
 1) test requires user authentication on all actions (RumblWeb.VideoControllerTest)
     test/rumbl_web/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:4
     ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Rumbl.Multimedia.list_user_videos/1

     The following arguments were given to Rumbl.Multimedia.list_user_videos/1:
     
         # 1
         nil
     
     Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):
     
         def list_user_videos(%Rumbl.Accounts.User{} = user)
     
     code: get(conn, Routes.video_path(conn, :index)),
     stacktrace:
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl/multimedia.ex:107: Rumbl.Multimedia.list_user_videos/1
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl_web/controllers/video_controller.ex:18: RumblWeb.VideoController.index/3
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl_web/controllers/video_controller.ex:1: RumblWeb.VideoController.action/2
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl_web/controllers/video_controller.ex:1: RumblWeb.VideoController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:352: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl_web/endpoint.ex:1: RumblWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl_web/endpoint.ex:1: RumblWeb.Endpoint.call/2
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:225: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
       test/rumbl_web/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:7: (test)


Finished in 0.2 seconds
4 tests, 1 failure
```

My repo: https://github.com/zervis/rumbl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no current user logged in, hence [`Multimedia.list_user_videos/1`](https://github.com/zervis/rumbl/blob/cb4973f7ea4ddcde4387decf33cc5c5ebc466306/lib/rumbl_web/controllers/video_controller.ex#L10) hets called with `nil` and there is no such clause handling `nil` (it expects the user struct only.)

I believe `videos` resource should go through `:authenticate_user` plug, as `manage` does.

Comment: That guided me to compare my router file with the source one and I've found the problem. Now test passes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here:

https://harfangk.github.io/2016/10/09/programming-phoenix-example-code-issues.html

If test "requires user authentication on all actions" fails, it’s likely that you made a similar mistake as I did. Check your rumbl/web/router.ex and see if it look like this.

```
scope "/", Rumbl do
  pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

  resources "/videos", VideoController
  resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
  resources "/session", SessionController, only: [:new, :create, :delete]
  get "/", PageController, :index
end

scope "/manage", Rumbl do
  pipe_through [:browser, :authenticate_user]

  resources "/videos", VideoController
end
```

Delete the line resources "videos", VideoController in scope "/", Rumbl do … end block. You probably misread the output result of resource generation in Generating Resources, Chapter 6 (PDF page 92-93) and understood it as an instruction to add resources "/videos", VideoController to rumbl/web/router.ex.

Note: in latest book, the 'misread' part is in Generating Web Interfaces, page 103.

Comment: This is 100% what caused my error, though my scope above is for `RumblWeb`, not `Rumbl`